# Comparing a random list to an ordered list in Java?

Tags: java, minecraft

I am working an idea that I was hoping to use in a Minecraft mod. Basically I want to have an object that contains a list of classes (e.g. minecraft items). I then want the items to be throw into a container by the player in order to create a recipe. If anyone has played with Thaumcraft then they would get the basic idea.

Anyone this is where I am lost.

I am searching for a way to create take the list of items that are in the container and determine if the recipe list has been statisfied. Normally I would think I could do this with a simple compare method that matches up the two lists. But the kicker is the player has the ability to insert the items into the container at random so I need to way to compare a random order against an ordered list.

So basically what I am looking for is this;

- List 1 (the player's list) *Will always be a specific order since its
  a recipe
- List 2 (the container's internal list) *Has a potential to be random

I need to search the container to see if List 1 matches List 2.

How could I go about this? Is using a list (Literally a Java List class) the right idea at all?

Comment: Copy them to temporary lists, and sort them before comparing with each other. Or, if the list can't contain duplicates, then create temporary Sets and compare those.

Comment: Making a copy of the lists would be a good start. Are you saying to use sets if I have a requirement where I need 3 of some item instead of just 1?

Comment: Sets would actually prevent you from having 3 of some item as you cannot have duplicate entries in a set.

Comment: If you compare Sets, then order is not relevant. But Sets can't contain duplicates, so if you have a situation where you need the same items twice or more, then Sets are not a good option.

Comment: So if I needed to specify a count of a specific item I would have to take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to sort each list. Then you could do an item-by-item comparison.  If the lists are the same size, and the elements at each index match, then the lists themselves are a match.

Even if the order of list 1 cannot change, then simply clone it, sort the clone, and compare it to the sorted version of list 2.